# How to use git with ssh on github https repository addresses?

Tags: git, github, ssh, https

I want to clone some github repositories to computers that have only access to github via an SSH tunnel.

I can use the ssh addresses to clone simple repositories without problems.

When a repository contains submodules, the access method is controled by `.gitsubmodules` which often default to https addresses (since this is the recommended way by github).

Is there a way to tell git submodules that it should always use ssh access, even when the address of a submodule is an https address?

Having to clone a repo and modify its `.gitsubmodules` just to be able to clone it through an ssh tunnel seems retarded. Hardcoding the access method in a `.gitsubmodules` file instead of letting your users choose the appropiate method seems pretty retarded too. I guess there must be a better way but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use git to rewrite the urls

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

You may include a hostname in the expression to restrict the rewrite to a specific host

```
 git config --global url."https://github.com".insteadOf git://github.com
```

If you do not whant the rewrite rules to be global then just add it to your local scope instead.

See more under section `url.<base>.insteadOf` at http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config

Comment: I like this answer more but I don't know about setting it globally in the event that certain repos are only available via HTTPS (unless your specifically unable to as the OP is)

Comment: maybe url."git@github.com:".insteadOf https://github.com/ will work for github, gonna try (UPDATE: It works, thanks!)

Comment: @osxi, you may just add the rewrite rules to the local scope instead.

Comment: @gnzlbg, thanx for the feedback, I clarified the the answer

Answer (score 1):

Changing the values in `.gitmodules` is a common way to change the protocol for submodules followed by a `git submodule sync` to update the remote repository locations.